# Adding a dynamic linked library in compilation command makes my program much slower

Tags: c++, linux, g++, stdvector, .so

#### Description

I have compiled kahypar(https://github.com/kahypar/kahypar) as a dynamic linked library **libkahypar.so**, and add it in the compilation command:

- With adding kahypar: g++ -O3 naive_test.cc libkahypar.so -o naive_test
- Without adding kahypar: g++ -O3 naive_test.cc  -o naive_test

I found that **adding libkahypar.so would makes my program much slower** (9.5s for without adding libkahypar.so and 37.8s for with adding libkahypar.so), even if I didn't use any kahypar APIs.

Here's my code:

naive_test.cc

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <vector>

static double WallTime()
{
  struct timeval tv;
  const int status = gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

  double tee;
  if (status == 0)
    tee = (double)(tv.tv_sec) + ((double)(tv.tv_usec)) * 1.0e-6;
  else
    tee = 0.0;

  return tee;
}

int main () {
  double total_time = 0.0;
  size_t len = 300000;

  for (int t = 0; t < 100; t++) {
    auto t0 = WallTime();
    std::vector<double> vec(len, 5.0);

    double temp = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        temp++;

        for (int k = 0; k < len; k++) {
          vec[k] = k + temp;
        }
      }
    }

    total_time += WallTime() - t0;
    std::cout << "Total time: " << total_time << "s" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

#### Result

Here I show the first 10 outputs with/out libkahypar.so:

**With libkahypar.so:**

Total time: 0.379228s

Total time: 0.751161s

Total time: 1.12916s

Total time: 1.5002s

Total time: 1.8718s

Total time: 2.24416s

Total time: 2.6204s

Total time: 2.99796s

Total time: 3.43391s

Total time: 3.81457s

**Without libkahypar.so:**

Total time: 0.107761s

Total time: 0.199389s

Total time: 0.290616s

Total time: 0.381933s

Total time: 0.473968s

Total time: 0.564921s

Total time: 0.656314s

Total time: 0.748251s

Total time: 0.85151s

Total time: 0.961246s

#### Environment

GCC version: 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5) (GCC)

System: CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6240 CPU @ 2.60GHz

This problem is so weird, I have no idea that why adding a dynamic library makes my program much slower. Any idea will be helpful to me!

I expect whether I add the dynamic library or not will not effect the performance of my code.

Comment: Does libkahypar.so have 29.3s worth of initialization?

Comment: this code doesn't use `std::vector`? Is it the code that's causing the problem? Please show a [mre]

Comment: @user7860670 nothing wrong with directly linking to a library file, its no different to using `-L` and `-l`, they just search for a library in the given directories then directly link to the file they found

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks for your correction! I made a mistake on the code, and I have corrected it now. This version is the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Eljay Thanks for your comment! I added the first 10 outputs with/out libkahypar.so. You can see that the time cost increase evenly in each iteration, i.e., the overhead it's not  caused by initialization

Comment: That is odd.  I wonder if the lib is spinning up a thread pool and busy burning CPU cycles.  I'd **profile** the program and see where it is busy spending CPU time.